# How can I safely find a duplicate values in dict?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, unique

```
{
  "50": [2110,1,94],
  "51": [2105,1,95],
  "52": [2105,1,85],
  "53": [2105,1,95],
}
```

I would like to return  a list as follow:

```
["51","53"]
```

Comment: Why does it matter that the values are lists? Do you have a solution for dicts where the values are _not_ lists? How does that fail if you try to use it with the data structure in your question?

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = {
    "50": [2110, 1, 94],
    "51": [2105, 1, 95],
    "52": [2105, 1, 85],
    "53": [2105, 1, 95],
}

duplicates = defaultdict(list)
for key, values in d.items():
    duplicates[tuple(values)].append(key)

res = [values for values in duplicates.values() if len(values) > 1]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
[['51', '53']]
```